# Error: Unable to resolve module when using shared library

Tags: react-native, expo, shared, managed, eas

I am building react native mobile app via `npx eas build -p android` with expo 49. This error is just related to path while building hence I haven't included environment info in detail. App is running fine in simulator othewise. Someone with prior similar experience should be able to figure this out. I am open to provide details if required.

I am able to run app in ios and android simulator by running `npx expo start --ios` and `npx expo start --android` just fine. However when I try to build using `eas` it fails for the error:

> Error: Unable to resolve module ./shared-lib/App from /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js:

None of these files exist:

- shared-lib/App(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)
- shared-lib/App/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)

> 1 | import App from './shared-lib/App';

```
|                  ^
```

2 | export default App

Error: Unable to resolve module ./shared-lib/App from /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js:

---

Now I tell you what I am doing. I have got a `shared-lib` directory parallel to App.js and index.js in root. I am using shared-lib folder as a git submodule to be used in multiple apps as a common code base. I am including shared-lib/App.js inside root App.js like:

```js
import App from './shared-lib/App';
export default App
```

I am attaching a folder structure here:

[image]

I am including files from shared-lib in all over the project. For example this is in ./LoginScreen.jsx

```
....
import ForgotPasswordLink from '../shared-lib/ForgotPasswordLink'

....

import {apiConfig, style as __style, fonts as __fontf} from '../shared-lib/config';
```

How do I make builder to know about the use of `shared-lib` in my project so that it can build successfully?

Comment: It was my mistake. I was building using expo command `eas build`. Since the `shared-lib` was listed in .gitignore it was not being bundled in the build. I removed it from .gitignore when running `eas build` and it worked!